# Polymorphism by generic types where types do not share a base class

Tags: c#, generics, expression-trees

**Background**

This is a refactoring question. I have a bunch of methods that more or less have exactly the same code but they act on different types. There is essentially one method per type and I want to combine them all into one that can use a generic type.

**Current Code**

Perhaps the below code will help explain what I'm trying -

The below methods differ mostly in the DbSet<> entity argument. Inside the method code, they use mostly exactly the same properties but in one or two lines they may use properties that are not shared by the entity types. For example, AccountId (from Account entity) and CustomerId (from Customer entity).

```
int? MethodToRefactor(DbSet<Account> entity, List someCollection, string[] moreParams)
        {
            int? keyValue = null;
            foreach (var itemDetail in someCollection)
            {
                string refText = GetRefTextBySource(itemDetail, moreParams);
//Only the below two lines differ in all MethodToRefactor because they use entity's properties that are not shared by all entities
                if (entity.Count(a => a.Name == refText) > 0)
                    keyValue = entity.Where(a => a.Name == refText).First().AccountId;
                if (...some conditional code...)
                    break;
            }
            return keyValue;
        }

int? MethodToRefactor(DbSet<Customer> entity, List someCollection, string[] moreParams)
{
            int? keyValue = null;
            foreach (var itemDetail in someCollection)
            {
                string refText = GetRefTextBySource(itemDetail, moreParams);
//Only the below two lines differ in all MethodToRefactor because they use entity's properties that are not shared by all entities
                if (entity.Count(c => c.CustomerName == refText) > 0)
                    keyValue = entity.Where(c => c.CustomerName == refText).First().CustomerId;
                if (...some conditional code...)
                    break;
            }
            return keyValue;
        }
```

Below is the code that calls the above methods -

```
void Caller()
        {
                    foreach (var entity in EntityCollection)
                    {
                        if (entity.Name == "Account")
                        {
                            id = MethodToRefactor(db.Accounts,...);
                        }
                        else if (entity.Name == "Customer")
                        {
                            id = MethodToRefactor(db.Customers,...);
                        }
            }
    }
```

**Problem**

This is not scalable for one thing because it requires copying/pasting a new MethodToRefactor for each newly added entity. It is difficult to maintain as well. I can perhaps refactor the code common to all MethodToRefactors in a separate method and do an ifelse inside it per entity but then I would basically be merging the Caller with MethodToRefactor. I'm looking for a neater solution with minimal changes in Caller method, as described below.

**Ideal/desired refactored code**

This is a great candidate for generic/template types. As seen below, I can change the actual entity to be a generic T and pass the two lines that do not use the common properties among the entities as expressions/methods.

Below is the C# type of pseudocode that demonstrates the ideal solution but I don't know how to actually do it in C#.

```
int? MethodToRefactor<T>(DbSet<T> entity, Expression<Func<T, T> filterMethod,
Expression<Func<T, T> getIdMethod, List someCollection, string[] moreParams) where T : Account, Customer //This will fail
{
            int? keyValue = null;
            foreach (var itemDetail in someCollection)
            {
                string refText = GetRefTextBySource(itemDetail, moreParams);
                if (filterMethod(entity) == true)
                    keyValue = getIdMethod(entity);
                if (...some conditional code...)
                    break;
            }
            return keyValue;
        }

void Caller()
        {
                    foreach (var entity in EntityCollection)
                    {
                        if (entity.Name == "Account")
                        {
                            id = MethodToRefactor<Account>(db.Accounts, () => {entity.Count(a => a.Name == refText) > 0}, () => {entity.Where(a => a.Name == refText).First().AccountId},...);
                        }
                        else if (entity.Name == "Customer")
                        {
                            id = MethodToRefactor<Customer>(db.Customer, () => {entity.Count(c => c.CustomerName == refText) > 0}, () => {entity.Where(c => c.CustomerName == refText).First().CustomerId},...);
                        }
            }
    }
```

**Benefits / Goals Achieved**
1. We combined all of MethodToRefactors into one and eliminated all duplicate code.
2. We abstracted away entity specific operations to the Caller. This is important because that logic is moved to the one logical place that knows how different entities differ from each other (Caller had a per entity ifelse to begin with) and how those differences are to be used.
2. By delegating the entity specific code to the Caller we also made it more flexible so that we don't have to create one MethodToRefactor per entity specific logic.

Note: I'm not a big fan of Adapter, Strategy etc, I prefer solutions that can achieve those goals using C# language features. That doesn't mean I'm anti-classical-design-patterns, it's just that I don't like the idea of creating a bunch of new classes when I can do it by refactoring into a couple of methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the entities do not have the same base class, the best you can do is to have a class constraint.

Since both expressions are essentially the same, you should just pass one expression and a function to get the key value from the entity.

The `Count` and `First` methods can also be merged into a single statement and then checking for `null`.

```
int? MethodToRefactor<T>(DbSet<T> entities, Func<string, Expression<Func<T, bool>>> expressionFilter, Func<T, int> getIdFunc, IList<string> someCollection, string[] moreParams)
    where T : class
{
    int? keyValue = null;
    foreach (var itemDetail in someCollection)
    {
        string refText = GetRefTextBySource(itemDetail, moreParams);
        var entity = entities.FirstOrDefault(expressionFilter(refText));
        if (entity != null)
        {
            keyValue = getIdFunc(entity);
        }
        if (...some conditional code...)
            break;
    }
    return keyValue;
}
```

You would call the method like this

```
id = MethodToRefactor<Account>(db.Accounts, txt => a => a.Name == txt, a => a.AccountId, ...);
id = MethodToRefactor<Customer>(db.Customers, txt => c => c.CustomerName == txt, c => c.CustomerId, ...);
```

Comment: Thank you. I just tried it and the `var entity = entities.FirstOrDefault(filterExpression(refText));` line seems to throw "Method name expected" error. Not sure what's causing it.

Comment: it's because the method given to FirstOrDefault doesn't have the good signature. FirstOrDefault need a method like this Func<T, bool>, you are giving Func<T, string, bool>. Or it can be due to your expression. Anyone, correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not really experienced with expressions for the moment.

Comment: entities.FirstOrDefault(e => filterExpression(e, refText))

Comment: I've updated the sample to use a `Func` that returns an `Expression` to ensure that the `IQueryable` `FirstOrDefault` works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it.

Given a type `T`, all we need is an accessor to a `string` property to be compared with `refText` and also an accessor to a `int` property for `keyValue`. The first is expressed by `Expression<Func<T, string>> nameSelector` and the second by `Expression<Func<T, int>> keySelector`, so these should be the additional parameters to the `MethodToRefactor`.

What about the implementation, the code

```
if (entity.Count(a => a.Name == refText) > 0)
     keyValue = entity.Where(a => a.Name == refText).First().AccountId;
```

can be made more optimal (using a single database query returning just one field) like this (pseudo code):

```
keyValue = entity.Where(e => nameSelector(e) == refText)
                 .Select(e => (int?)keySelector(e))
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

The `int?` cast is needed to allow returning `null` when `refText` does not exist.

In order to implement that, we need two expressions derived from the arguments:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = e => nameSelector(e) == refText;
```

and

```
Expression<Func<T, int?>> nullableKeySelector = e => (int?)keySelector(e);
```

Of course the above is not a valid syntax, but can easily be build with `System.Linq.Expressions`.

With all that being said, the refactored method could be like this:

```
int? MethodToRefactor<T>(
    DbSet<T> entitySet,
    Expression<Func<T, string>> nameSelector,
    Expression<Func<T, int>> keySelector,
    List someCollection,
    string[] moreParams)
    where T : class
{
    int? keyValue = null;
    foreach (var itemDetail in someCollection)
    {
        string refText = GetRefTextBySource(itemDetail, moreParams);

        // Build the two expressions needed
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(nameSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(refText)),
                nameSelector.Parameters);

        var nullableKeySelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int?>>(
            Expression.Convert(keySelector.Body, typeof(int?)),
            keySelector.Parameters);

        // Execute the query and process the result
        var key = entitySet.Where(predicate).Select(nullableKeySelector).FirstOrDefault();
        if (key != null)
            keyValue = key;

        if (...some conditional code...)
            break;
    }
    return keyValue;
}
```

and the usage:

*Account:*

```
id = MethodToRefactor(db.Accounts, e => e.Name, e => e.AccountId, ...);
```

*Customer:*

```
id = MethodToRefactor(db.Customer, e => e.CustomerName, e => e.CustomerId, ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand you do not have a base class, but your method is definately only applicable to classes of your dal. As such, i would definatelty mark the available classes with an interface. This will help others on your team to get a hint of where they can use your method. I always added a base interface to my dal classes.

I do not think defining the key property is the responsability of your caller. The key is something the entity should provide.

Having an interface, you can already abstract the key property to it, having

```
internal interface IEntity
{
    int Key { get; }
}
```

Of course you can have it generic by the keytype, if you have more than one.

As for your search term property, this is something you need to decide. Either it is also a property of the entity (if this property/ies (why only one???) is used in more than one place), or is used only in this method. I would guess for the sake of simplicity, this is used only here.

In this case your method would look like:

```
int? MethodToRefactor<T>(EfContext context, IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, string>>> searchFields, IEnumerable<string> someCollection, string[] moreParams)
    where T : class, IEntity
{
    int? keyValue = null;
    foreach (var itemDetail in someCollection)
    {
        string refText = GetRefTextBySource(itemDetail, moreParams);
        if (searchFields.Any())
        {
            var filter = searchFields.Skip(1).Aggregate(EqualsValue(searchFields.First(), refText), (e1, e2) => CombineWithOr(e1, EqualsValue(e2, refText)));
            var entity = context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(filter);
            if (entity != null)
            {
                keyValue = entity.Key;
            }
            if (... some condition ...)
                break;
        }
    }
    return keyValue;
}

private Expression<Func<T, bool>> EqualsValue<T>(Expression<Func<T, string>> propertyExpression, string strValue)
{
    var valueAsParam = new {Value = strValue}; // this is just to ensure that your strValue will be an sql parameter, and not a constant in the sql
         // this will speed up further calls by allowing the server to reuse a previously calculated query plan
         // this is a trick for ef, if you use something else, you can maybe skip this
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(propertyExpression.Body, Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Constant(valueAsParam), valueAsParam.GetType().GetProperty("Value"))), 
        propertyExpression.Parameters); // here you can cache the property info
}

private class ParamReplacer : ExpressionVisitor // this i guess you might have already
{
    private ParameterExpression NewParam {get;set;}
    public ParamReplacer(ParameterExpression newParam)
    {
        NewParam = newParam;
    }
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression expression)
    {
        return NewParam;
    }
}

private Expression<Func<T, bool>> CombineWithOr<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> e1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> e2) // this is also found in many helper libraries
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Or(e1.Body, new ParamReplacer(e1.Parameters.Single()).VisitAndConvert(e2.Body, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name)), e1.Parameters);
}
```

Now this will obviously require you to implement the key property on all your entities, which in my opinion is not such a bad thing. Apparently you use your key properties anyways for other stuff too (otherwise why would this method return a key only).

On another note, you are retrieving the whole entity when a match is found, but then you care only about the key. This could be made better by retrieving only the key, e.g. adding a select to the end of the expression. Unfortunately in this case you would need a bit more "magic" in order for ef (or your linq provider) to understand the .Select(e => e.Key) expression (at least ef won't out of the box). Since i hope you need the whole entity in your "... some condition...", im not including this version in this answer (also to keep it short :P).

So finally your caller would look like:

```
 void Caller()
    {
                foreach (var entity in EntityCollection)
                {
                    if (entity.Name == "Account")
                    {
                        id = MethodToRefactor<Account>(db, new [] {a => a.Name}, ...);
                    }
                    else if (entity.Name == "Customer")
                    {
                        id = MethodToRefactor<Customer>(db, new [] {c => c.FirstName, c => c.LastName}, ...);
                    }
        }
}
```